# Call back before save : SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a polymorphic relation beewten "sleeps" and "pois".

```
class Sleep < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :poi, as: :poitable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poi
```

In my sleep controller :

```
 def create
   @sleep = Sleep.new(sleep_params)
   @sleep.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
   if @sleep.save
     redirect_to track_sleeps_path, notice: t(".sleep_created")
   else
    render :new
   end
 end
```

and params :

```
 def sleep_params
   params.require(:sleep).permit(
    :name,
    .......,
    { :poi_attributes => [..., :latitude, :longitude, :lonlat, :poitable_id, :poitable_type] } )
 end
```

My Poi controller :

```
class Poi < ApplicationRecord
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :will_save_change_to_address?
  before_create :set_st_point
  belongs_to :poitable, polymorphic: true, optional:true
```

When I'm creating a new instance I get longitude and latitude by geocoder. It work fine.

But I would like to set lonlat by the function set_st_point

```
  def set_st_point
    if latitude.present? && longitude.present?
      self.lonlat = "POINT(#{longitude} #{latitude})"
    end
  end
```

I've been trying "before_save", "before_create" but the field lonlat stay empty.

How can I resolve this ?

Edit :

I'm trying to do :

```
  def set_st_point
    if latitude.present? && longitude.present?
     self.lonlat = "POINT(#{longitude} #{latitude})"
     self.save!
   end
  end
```

But now, I have a  SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack level too deep indicates it went to infinite loop. If you save anything in before save, after save, before create, after create, before update, after update which call callback again it will cause stack level too deep.

In above code i found that set_st_point is called in before create and saving it which caused here Stack level too deep. Data is not saving after setting also that must be some other issue that you have to check if once you set 'lonlat ' some other place it is resetting it.

Once simple fix is in after create you can say

```
 .update_column('lonlat',"POINT(#{longitude} #{latitude})")
```

update column will not call any callback this must be there in after create.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation... it work fine ;)